# How do I only allow for a message box to show a maxiumum of 5 times?

Tags: c#, messagebox

I have a message box that I want to display a maximum of 5 times.

here is my code

the message box I want to display max 5 times is the "would you like to add an additional driver to policy?"

```
            DialogResult answer = MessageBox.Show("Would you like to add an additional driver to policy?", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information); ;
            if (answer == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                frmAdditionalDriver form = new frmAdditionalDriver();
                form.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                frmInsurancePolicy form = new frmInsurancePolicy();
                form.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
```

Comment: What about a counter? I mean like `int counter = 0;` and then `if(++counter <= 5)`...

Comment: That sounds like you should have a "Do not ask me again" checkbox on the Message Box.

Comment: Hi @Kitty, 
If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark so others can use that for further references.

Comment: hello @Clint no neither will work for me it continually asks me if i want to add another driver

Comment: interesting, can you show share the update code snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put the code in a loop, which continues until the maximum times have been reached. Note that I've changed your `Show` to `ShowDialog`, which will pause execution of the loop until the other form is closed:

```
var maxEntries = 5;
var totalEntries = 0;

Hide();

while (totalEntries < maxEntries)
{
    DialogResult answer = 
        MessageBox.Show("Would you like to add an additional driver to policy?" 
            "Info", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    if (answer == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        new frmAdditionalDriver().ShowDialog();
    }
    else
    {
        new frmInsurancePolicy().ShowDialog();
    }

    totalEntries++;
}

Show();
```

If you also want to exit the loop if they ever answer `"No"`, then we can use the loop slightly differently by using the dialog result as part of the condition:

```
var maxEntries = 5;
var totalEntries = 0;

DialogResult answer = 
    MessageBox.Show("Would you like to add an additional driver to policy?",
        "Info", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

Hide();

while (totalEntries < maxEntries && answer == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    totalEntries++;

    if (answer == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        new frmAdditionalDriver().ShowDialog();                   
    }

    answer = MessageBox.Show("Would you like to add an additional driver to policy?",
        "Info", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}

new frmInsurancePolicy().ShowDialog();

Show();
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can simply create a Class say MessageBoxConstraints**

```
Class MessageBoxConstraints
{
    public int Counter { get; set; } = 0; 

    public void Show()
    {
        if(Counter<5)
        {
          Initiate();
        }

    }

    private void Initiate ()
    {
        Counter++;
        DialogResult answer = MessageBox.Show("Would you like to add an additional driver to policy?", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information); ;
            if (answer == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                frmAdditionalDriver form = new frmAdditionalDriver();
                form.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
            else
            {
                frmInsurancePolicy form = new frmInsurancePolicy();
                form.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }

    }

}
```

---

**And invoke its Show() from your client**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        var popUp = new MessageBoxConstraints();
        popUp.Show();

    }
}
```